# Sample quantile of order p

Tags: statistics, quantile

My book says the following :

"Let $X_{(1)}, X_{(2)}, ..., X_{(n)}$ be a set of values ordered in ascending order ($X_{(1)} \leq X_{(2)} \leq ... \leq X_{(n)})$. For a given $p$ ($0 \le p \le 1$), the $pth$ sample quantile $q_p$ is a value that has a proportion $p$ of the sample taking values smaller than it and a proportion $1-p$ taking values larger than it."

It then says that the value of this quantile is $X_{(1+(n-1)p)}$.

**My question** : why does the $pth$ quantile is at the index $1+(n-1)p$ of the ordered sample? Is there an intuitive way to understand this?

Answer (score 0):

It is often difficult to explain rationales for formulas involving quantiles.

There are many slightly different ways to define *quantile*.  For small
samples of integer data, the variations in results from one definition
to another can be very noticeable.

Different textbooks and software use different definitions. R statistical
software gives rigorous accounts of nine different definitions on the
help screen that is accessible from the Console by typing `? quantile`. Here is a brief
demonstration that shows a few of the differences.

The vector `x` is a sorted sample of size 20 from $Binom(50, 1/3).$

```
x
## 12 13 13 13 14 15 15 15 15 16 16 16 16 16 17 17 18 19 19 21
```

The statement `quantile(x)` without further arguments gives percentiles
0, 25, 50, 75, and 100, based on the 7th (default) of these definitions. Other
definitions can be invoked with arguments such as `type=1`, and so on.

```
quantile(x, type=1)
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
  12   14   16   17   21 
quantile(x, type=2)
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
12.0 14.5 16.0 17.0 21.0 
quantile(x, type=3)
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
  12   14   16   17   21 
quantile(x, type=4)
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
  12   14   16   17   21 
quantile(x, type=5)
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
12.0 14.5 16.0 17.0 21.0
```

And so on. Exact discrepancies among definitions depend on the particular random sample
generated.

Comment: My question is more about : based on the definition of my textbook, why the $pth$ quantile is at the index $1+(n-1)p$ of the ordered sample? I edited my question to make it clearer :)

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing the context in the book. _Speculate_ maybe something like this: There are $(n-1)$ 'gaps' between $n$ order statistics, so go approx index $(n-1)p$ (possibly noninteger) to get almost to the $p$th quantile, then add 1 to get all of the way, then take integer part of that for integer index number $\lfloor (n-1)p + 1 \rfloor.$